# Taking multiple lines of Input C++

Tags: c++, input

I want to take in multiple lines of input or rather input that is separated by spaces. I need to store the inputs in different values. Like if the input is a tax program: 2.3% *space* $2,300. I need to store 2.3 and 2,300 in different values. HOw can i do this?

Comment: why not take inputs by pressing enter ?

Comment: float rate, price; cin >> rate >> price;

Comment: it was a problem

Comment: Use Option Two given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301) as inspiration.

Comment: @seccpur it printer 2.3 and 2

Comment: Keep things simple, enter price as 2300 and not as 2,300, to avoid parsing etc